# Excel - Pivot table shows a field, but the source query lacks column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I am a newbie with Pivot tables. Received a sheet from client with an existing pivot table to analyze.

The pivot table targets a power-query that further targets a sql database.
As shown in image below, although pivot-table has a field named "Months", however the source power-query lacks any such column.

[image]

I thought it would be a calculated column added to pivot-table, but i created a separate pivot-table anew, and it gets the same field "Months" to start with.

Can you please help me understand where this field might be coming from?

Comment: Within the pivot table: Do a right mouseclick on a pivotfield which is derived from date values (e. g. "Apr" in your column header). Then you can select "group" and see, how a single date field can be shown as year or quarter or month or ... (or all of them) *additionally* and automatically by Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Excel Pivot Tables can automatically group dates by Year, Quarter, Month, Date.

You can choose to ungroup this date field.

Comment: please note, Months is shows as a field in pivot table, how is it?